# How to do nested query in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am searching to map a nested foreach loop as Entity Framework query but have failed so far. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

This is the loop I want to map.

```
foreach (var v in db.Users)
{
    if(v.Active == 1)
    {
        foreach(Role r in v.Roles)
            if(r.Name.Equals("Management"))
                us.Add(v);
    }
}

var sa = (from u in db.Users
          where u.Roles == from r in db.Roles
          where r.Name == "Management" select r).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
var result = db.Users.Where(u => u.Active && u.Roles.Any(r => r.Name.Equals("Management"))).ToList();
```

P.S. It seems that you forgot to add continue inside your "if(r.Name.Equals("Management"))".

Comment: There are a lot of users with management role so I can't add continue there.

Comment: I mean case when there is a user that has 2 Roles with Name == "Management" (is it possible? :) ). In such case that user will be added twice to the result collection.

Comment: @ilyakorover yes. If you want only the first one you can replace .Any( with .FirstOrDefault(

Comment: @peva27 if you change Any to FirstOrDefault in the query above, you will get an error :)